# Spring Security Authentication By User

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing a basic note app with spring boot. When a GET request comes to NoteController, i wanna check if user has this note. In example note that has id 1 belongs to UserA . If UserB tries to get this note with going this url : /note/1, i don't want UserB to access this note. To Solve this problem, everytime a request comes to NoteController i get the authenticated user from SecurityContextHolder and check if note belongs to this user. Is there anything better than this?

NoteController

```
package app.controller;

import app.entity.Note;
import app.entity.User;
import app.service.NoteService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/note")
public class NoteController
{
    @Autowired
    private NoteService noteService;
    @PostMapping
    public Note save(@RequestBody Note note)
    {
        User user=(User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        note.setUser(user);
        noteService.save(note);
        return note;
    }
    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> update(@RequestBody Note note)
    {
        User user=(User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if(noteService.findById(note.getId()).getUser().getId()==user.getId())
        {
            noteService.update(note);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Note> findById(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        User user=(User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        Note note=noteService.findById(id);
        if(note.getUser().getId()==user.getId())
            return new ResponseEntity<>(note,HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
    @GetMapping
    public List<Note> findByUser()
    {
        User user=(User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        return noteService.findByUser(user);
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteById(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        User user=(User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        Note note=noteService.findById(id);
        if(note.getUser().getId()==user.getId())
        {
            noteService.deleteById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
package app.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private TokenFilter tokenFilter;
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/note").hasAuthority("CREATE")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/note").hasAuthority("READ")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/note").hasAuthority("UPDATE")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/note").hasAuthority("DELETE")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenFilter,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `findById()` call results are given for authorization check , which means the logic may be moved to a common place , i.e `findById()`.

The same authorization logic can be done using [Method Security Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#method-security-expressions) : [@PostAuthorize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PostAuthorize.html) annotation

An example would be as follows. `NoteService.findById(id)` method may be modified to have this check and the user check logic from controller methods may be removed.

```
@PostAuthorize("returnObject.user.id == principal.id")
public Note findById(Long id)
{
   return noteRepository.findById(id);
}
```

Here the `@PostAuthorize` is done on the built-in `returnObject`.

Also remember to enable GlobalMethodSecurity as follows for the Pre and Post annotations to work

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
//...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Is there anything else to use in other methods in noteController ?

Comment: The `@PostAuthorize` anntation will replace the existing user authorization code logic. Nothing else needs to be done.